Propagators in the Klein-Gordon theory
I am currently doing QFT  to be more precise the theory of the Klein-Gordon field and I'm a bit confused about the propagators. That's how I understood it:
In non relativistic quantum mechanics the amplitude for a free particle propagating from $x_0$ to $x$ is given by:
$$U(t) = c \cdot e^{i \frac{m}{2t}(x - x_0)} \neq 0$$
That means in non-relativistic quantum mechanics, a free particle can propagate “instantaneously” over the entire space, which violates causality. QFT should now solve the causality problem. The probability that a measurment performed at one position will be able to influence another measurment is given by: $$[\phi(x),\phi(y)] = \Delta(x-y)$$ where $$\Delta(x-y) = \int \frac{d^3\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2E_{\mathbf{p}}} \left(e^{-ip \cdot (x-y)} - e^{ip \cdot (x-y)}\right)$$  is the causal distribution. I can also write this in form as a lorentzinvariant quantity: $$i\Delta(x-y) = \int d^4p \, \frac{\epsilon(p_0)}{(2\pi)^3} \delta(p^2 - m^2) e^{-ip(x-y)}$$
For space-like events at different points in time, there is always one inertial frame, so that these two events occur simultaneously in this inertial frame take place simultaneously and are still spacelike to each other. This means that the causal distribution disappears for all spacelike distances and thus guarantees the microcausality of all events.So Delta indicates when a result can take place causally? Now comes the point where I'm struggling, depending on how I make the transition from the 3d integral to the 4d integral, I can derive other propagators. So different contours lead to different propagators due to the residue theorem. If I just include one pole for the contour integral I get the Feynman Propagator $$
\Delta_F(x-y)=\theta(x^0-y^0) \langle 0 |[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle +\theta(y^0-x^0) \langle 0 |[\phi(y),\phi(x)]|0\rangle = \langle 0 | T(\phi(x) \phi(y)) |0\rangle
$$ where T is the time ordering opertor. And if I include both poles I get the Retarded Propagator $$\Delta_R(x-y) = \theta(x^0-y^0) \langle 0 |[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle$$ What is the physical significance of these propagators?

There is no position observable in QFT. As such there is no position basis and hence no way of talking about probability amplitudes from particles to go from a certain point to another. The closest one gets in the relativistic setting is the Newton-Wigner position that doesn’t help much. This whole thing is a common misconception about the QFT field propagator.

Just want to comment that instantaneous propagation does not break causality in a non-relativistic theory.  You still see the particle only after it is created.

Your first equation seems to have an error. The $(x-x_0)$ in the exponent should be squared to get something with dimensions of action in the exponent. And presumably you set $\hbar=1$.
